# Angularjs - UI Boostrap: Accordion Open and close all

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-ui-bootstrap

i have written some code to open and close all tabs of an accordion respectively use a separate 'open' and 'close' button. How ever it requires me to dynamically add a key value pair(a Boolean value) to my json data.

What is the best practice in this situation? should i add the Boolean value as a static json element or is it OK to dynamically add values when their sole purpose is for visual structure and not relevant to actual object data.

**HTML/Angular directives**

```
<div id="app" ng-app="demoApp">
  <div id="controller" ng-controller="demoAppCtrl">    
    <uib-accordion close-others="false">    
      <div class="btn-group form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="toggle(true)">Open</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="toggle(false)">Close</button>
      </div>      
      <uib-accordion-group is-open="hero.state" ng-click="setOpened(false)" ng-repeat="hero in heroes">
        <uib-accordion-heading>
          {{hero.name}}
        </uib-accordion-heading>
        {{hero.bio}}
      </uib-accordion-group>    
    </uib-accordion>    
  </div>  
</div>
```

**Javascript/Angular**

```
var app = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('demoAppCtrl', function($scope) {

  // This json object contain only one entry as an example
  $scope.heroes = [
    {'name': 'Captain America', 'team': 'Avengers', 'bio': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vitae metus placerat, condimentum nisl et, accumsan sapien. Quisque molestie magna nulla, id malesuada sem interdum a.'}
  ];

  $scope.addDefaultState = function(val) {
    for (var i=0;i<$scope.heroes.length;i++) {
      $scope.heroes[i].state = val;
    }
  } 
  $scope.addDefaultState(false);

  $scope.toggle = function(status) {
    $scope.heroes.forEach(function(e) {
      e.state = status;
    });
  }

});
```

[codepen.io - Working example (with corrections)](http://codepen.io/fmrogers/pen/Razexg?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the static json should not contain Boolean state value. It is okay to dynamically add values for visual presentation.

In your code the function *addDefaultState* is not needed. The *is-open="hero.state"* will take care of default state cause initially it will not find state and will consider it as false. So you change your code like below it should work too:

```
var app = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('demoAppCtrl', function($scope) {

  // This json object contain only one entry as an example
  $scope.heroes = [
    {'name': 'Captain America', 'team': 'Avengers', 'bio': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vitae metus placerat, condimentum nisl et, accumsan sapien.'}
  ];

  $scope.toggle = function(status) {
    $scope.heroes.forEach(function(e) {
      e.state = status;
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i am glad you agree with me in regards to the json data. Having said that you are correct about the `.addDefaultState()` function. It was unnecessary and removes the issue of the json data entirely. One question however, should i keep the value `hero.state` or replace it with a simple `false` value ? EDIT: Changing `is-open` to `is-open=false` does not work.

Comment: Yes, you need to keep hero.state in there cause toggle function is setting true/false to the state model. The is-open is using that model.